# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**TransationList.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import TransationForm from './transactionsForm';

class TransationList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        list: this.returnList()
    }

    returnList() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('transations') == null)
            localStorage.setItem('transactions',JSON.stringify([]))
           return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transations'))
    }

    onAddorEdit = (data) =>{
        var list = this.returnList()
        list.push(data)
        localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify([list]))
        this.setState({list})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <TransationForm 
                    onAddorEdit = {this.onAddorEdit}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TransationList;
```

Comment: Your function this.returnList() is returning null that's why you are facing error

Comment: how can i fix, I am new to react can you explain, error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null"

Comment: another file name transactionForm.js 
class TransationForm extends React.Component {

state = {
    bAccountNo: '',
    IFSC: '',
    Branch: '',
    Amount: ''
}

handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onAddorEdit(this.state)
}

Comment: Please check my answer. I think you have typo in your key while adding and fetching data from your local storage.

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here problem is you are storing blank array with key as `transactions`, but you are fetching data key `transations`. Note `c` is missing from other key.

So your return statement should be:-

```
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactions'))
```

Comment: If you find this answer useful then please upvote it so other people can also find it. Thanks!